# Maven Build failing with Package does not exist when building module what include another module

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-plugin

I have four modules (library, web, jobs, database) and a parent. library, web, and database modules are building successfully, but when I'm trying to build jobs module I have some errors "package com.project.web.rest does not exist". Module jobs contain library and web packages's class, which I already built. I mean when I'm building jobs, library and web are already built.

While building jobs module, it doesn't refer anything from the web module. In the same time in java class import is working well.

import com.project.web.rest;

This is jobs module pom.xml file part:

```
    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Sibling -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-lib</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-web</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: did you run mvn:install when building ?

Comment: i run mvn -U clean install -DskipTests

Comment: Is your `parent` also an [aggregator (containing a `<modules>` section)](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation)? Showing the complete POM(s) (with masked confidential info, if necessary) usually helps to find an answer quicker.

Comment: @ВоваДк did you solve it?